# Why does my Route 53 domain say "server transfer prohibited"? It it a problem I need to fix?

Tags: webserver, amazon-aws, domain-forwarding, amazon-s3, route53

So recently I made the switch back and forth from a static website (s3 bucket) to lightsail (so I've had to reconfigure my R53 settings a few times, & of course something had to go wrong in the transition back to s3

So the Domain name status code is no longer 'ok'  as it was and has 'server transfer prohibited'

Mind you my s3 endpoint is still working fine and displays my pages

Really just need some guidance on my record sets as I'm thinking it's some thing to do with me changing them temporarily for lightsail

Too easy to get lost in the sea of AWS jargon

Comment: And yet you do not even provide the domain name so that people can troubleshoot it for you. EPP "serverTransferProhibited" status **may** happen during 60 days after a creation or a registrar change, per ICANN policies. This has no impact on the working of your domain name.

Comment: Http://whenbrainsbleed.org